# Reading csv file mapping with header in flutter

Tags: flutter, csv, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

**csv file - place.csv**

```
zipcode,name,long,lat,alt
60603,"Chicago, Illinois,USA",-87.62,41.88,186
11101,"New York City, NY, USA",-73.93,40.73,10
```

how to read and store this csv data in List format. I am using the CSV package but the data is not being read properly.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  //

  Future<List<String>> loadAsset() async {
    var myData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/data/place.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = CsvToListConverter(eol: "\r\n").convert(myData);
    //
    List<String> data = [];
    csvTable[0].forEach((value) {
      data.add(value.toString());
    });
    return data;
  }

  //
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('network test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: loadAsset(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              // this condition is important
              if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text('loading data'),
                );
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Center(child: Text(snapshot.data[index]));
                    });
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am using this code but the end of the line is not getting read instead, the last entry and the first entry of the new line are merged. How to get a different list of every column separately.

```
zipcode
name
long
lat
alt 60603
"Chicago, Illinois,USA"
-87.62
41.88
186 11101
"New York City, NY, USA"
-73.93
40.73
10
```

Here is the solution I am getting. The alt field is getting merged with the zipcode field.

Comment: This is most probably a problem of end-of-line encoding. BTW, I think `eol` default in the `csv` package is `"\r\n"`. Are you on Linux? Maybe you could try with just `"\n"`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a review of your code with a Domain Class `City` to retrieve typed data from your API / Asset File:

[image]

### Full source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part '66454899.csv.freezed.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cities'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<City>>(
          future: City.fromAssetCsv('assets/data/place.csv'),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done)
              return Center(child: Text('loading data'));
            if (snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data.isEmpty)
              return Center(
                child: Text('No data'),
              );
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data
                  .map<ListTile>(
                    (city) => ListTile(
                      title: Text(city.name),
                      subtitle: Text(
                          '${city.zipCode} (${city.longitude}, ${city.latitude})'),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

@freezed
abstract class City implements _$City {
  const factory City({
    int zipCode,
    String name,
    double longitude,
    double latitude,
    int alt,
  }) = _City;
  const City._();

  static City fromCsvRow(List<dynamic> csvRow) {
    return City(
      zipCode: csvRow[0] as int,
      name: csvRow[1] as String,
      longitude: csvRow[2] as double,
      latitude: csvRow[3] as double,
      alt: csvRow[4] as int,
    );
  }

  static List<City> fromCsvTable(List<List<dynamic>> csvTable) {
    return csvTable.skip(1).map((csvRow) => City.fromCsvRow(csvRow)).toList();
  }

  static List<City> fromCsvString(String csvString) =>
      City.fromCsvTable(CsvToListConverter().convert(csvString));

  static Future<List<City>> fromAssetCsv(String assetPath) async =>
      City.fromCsvString(await rootBundle.loadString(assetPath));

  // static Future<List<City>> fromNetworkCsv(String url) async =>
  //     City.fromCsvString(await http.get(url));
}
```

Comment: part '66454899.csv.freezed.dart'; I didn't get this line. Can you please explain.

Comment: I am using the [freezed package](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) for the `City` Class. It generates code inside the file `[66454899.csv.freezed.dart]`. The name of the file comes from my main file which is `[66454899.csv.dart]`. Freezed enforces immutability.

Comment: Note, you could easily implement the `City` Class without `@freezed` if it bothers you.

Comment: I am getting "No data" as output without freezed. What is in the [66454899.csv.dart] file? Can you plz explain.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently looping on the field of your `csvTable` Header Row.

Instead of:

```dart
csvTable[0].forEach((value) {
  data.add(value.toString());
});
```

It should probably be:

```dart
csvTable.forEach((value) {
  data.add(value.toString());
});
```

You could also use `map` instead of `forEach`:

```dart
List<String> data = csvTable.map((value) => value.toString()).toList();
```

Comment: I want to map the header names with the csv data. For example: zipcode: 60603, name: "NYC, NY, USA", and so on ...

Comment: Check my other answer, maybe that one would better fit your request.